# Conic sections checking my answers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-verification

> 1. A ball is thrown from $3$ ft. Equations: $x =  69t, y= 3+40t-16t^2$. 
>      How long is the ball in flight and how far it travel?

Answer: Eliminating the parameter and solving the quadratic give $x = 177.5$ so that's how far it travels. $t=177.5/69 = 2.57$.

> 2. An ellipse has foci $(\pm 2,0)$ and vertices $(\pm 3,0)$. Find the vertices of minor axis.

Answer: $h=k=0, c=0, a=3$ so $b = \sqrt{5}$. Therefore answer is $(0,\pm \sqrt{5})$.

> 3. A string is hung from $(-6,3), (6,3)$ so that it hangs down to just touch the origin at its vertex. What is the $y$ coordinate when $x =2$.

Answer: I worked out the parabola is $y=x^2/12$ so $y(2)= 1/3$.

Thanks.

Comment: Please visit http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference . It is a link to MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference wiki. MathJax will help you to write your questions more clearly and help readers to understand them more easily.

Comment: Please help someone - I don't need full method, just comfirmation

Answer (score 1):

> A ball is thrown from 3 ft. Equations: $x=69t$,$y=3+40t−16t^2$. How long is the ball in flight and how far does it travel?

Your answer is correct.  Here is an alternative approach using the parametric equations.  I have made the units explicit.

The ball remains in flight until it hits the ground.  If we set $y = 0$ and solve for $t$, we obtain 
\begin{align*}
0 & = 3~\text{ft} + \left(40~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}}\right)t - \left(16~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}^2}\right)t^2\\
\left(16~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}^2}\right)t^2 - \left(40~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}}\right)t & = 3~\text{ft}\\
t^2 - \left(\frac{5}{2}~\text{s}\right)t & = \frac{3}{16}~\text{s}^2\\
t^2 - \left(\frac{5}{2}~\text{s}\right)t + \frac{25}{16}~\text{s}^2 & = \frac{3}{16}~\text{s}^2 + \frac{25}{16}~\text{s}^2\\
\left(t - \frac{5}{4}~\text{s}\right)^2 & = \frac{28}{16}~\text{s}^2\\
t - \frac{5}{4}~\text{s} & = \pm\frac{2\sqrt{7}}{4}~\text{s}\\
t & = \frac{5 \pm 2\sqrt{7}}{4}~\text{s} 
\end{align*}
Since the balls hits the ground after it is released, we require that $t > 0$.  Hence,
$$t = \frac{5 + 2\sqrt{7}}{4}~\text{s} \approx 2.57~\text{s}$$ 
Substituting this value for $t$ in the equation $x = \left(69~\dfrac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}}\right)t$ yields
$$x = \left(69~\frac{\text{ft}}{\text{s}}\right)\left(\frac{5 + 2\sqrt{7}}{4}~\text{s}\right) \approx 177.5~\text{ft}$$

> An ellipse has foci $(\pm 2,0)$ and vertices $(\pm 3,0)$. Find the vertices of the minor axis.

You obtained the correct answer, so I assume you meant $c = 2$.

> A string is hung from $(−6,3)$, $(6,3)$ so that it hangs down to just touch the origin at its vertex. What is the $y$ coordinate when $x=2$?

The shape of a string that is suspended from two points is a [catenary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catenary) rather than a parabola.  If you were supposed to approximate its shape by a parabola, your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

All of them are correct, congrats.

I like to add to number 2 though.

I don't know what you did with $h = 0 = k$.

but a simple way is this :-

$a^2 = b^2 + c^2$ where $a$ is length semi major axis, $b$ length  is semi minor axis and $c$ is the distance of either foci from center.

$a$ and $b$ is given , thus you easily can find $c$.

Tell me in comments if you want the derivation of $a^2 = b^2 + c^2$ or not.